# No Class Def Found Error Android-Bolts Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, facebook-android-sdk, bolts-framework

I am using Android Studio (latest version) for developing my app. I use Parse as a backend solution. Everything was working smooth until i found out that parse have new release and i wanted to upgrade from **Parse-1.7.1.jar** to **Parse-1.8.3.jar** (*latest version*). 
Since parse now use Bolts lib i also added the library like this:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
```

> Parse.initialize();

Also i use the facebook-sdk for dont know if this have to do anything with this mess.

All i get in my Application onCreate method is this error

```
03-08 22:07:05.841  24519-24533/ant.flow E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'bolts.Task$TaskCompletionSource', referenced from method com.parse.ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.waitForOperationSetAndEventuallyPin
03-08 22:07:05.841  24519-24519/ant.flow E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ant.flow, PID: 24519
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bolts.BoltsExecutors
            at bolts.Task.<clinit>(Task.java:31)
            at com.parse.ParseSQLiteDatabase.<init>(ParseSQLiteDatabase.java:45)
            at com.parse.ParseSQLiteDatabase.openDatabaseAsync(ParseSQLiteDatabase.java:33)
            at com.parse.ParseSQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseAsync(ParseSQLiteOpenHelper.java:43)
            at com.parse.ParseSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabaseAsync(ParseSQLiteOpenHelper.java:39)
            at com.parse.OfflineStore.findAsync(OfflineStore.java:390)
            at com.parse.OfflineStore.findAsync(OfflineStore.java:354)
            at com.parse.ParsePin.getParsePin(ParsePin.java:22)
            at com.parse.ParseQuery.countFromLocalDatastoreAsync(ParseQuery.java:885)
            at com.parse.ParseQuery.access$1700(ParseQuery.java:78)
            at com.parse.ParseQuery$22.call(ParseQuery.java:1132)
            at com.parse.ParseQuery$22.call(ParseQuery.java:1128)
            at com.parse.ParseQuery.doWithRunningCheck(ParseQuery.java:912)
            at com.parse.ParseQuery.countInBackground(ParseQuery.java:1128)
            at com.parse.ParseInstallation.hasCurrentInstallationAsync(ParseInstallation.java:88)
            at com.parse.GcmRegistrar.updateAsync(GcmRegistrar.java:96)
            at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:240)
            at ant.flow.SocialApplication.onCreate(SocialApplication.java:33)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4581)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What version of Facebook SDK are you using? Can you also include the app/build.gradle file in the question?

Comment: I fixed the issue with the new Facebook SDK 4.0